# If $f$ is infinitely differentiable and equal to 0 on $(-\infty, 0]$, must $f$ be 0 everywhere else?

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-functions

While working on question A5 from the 2018 Putnam Exam, I ran into the following problem: if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is infinitely differentiable (i.e. smooth) and $f(x) = 0$ when $x \in (-\infty, 0]$, must $f$ be $0$ everywhere else?

What I've figured so far: Clearly $f^{(n)}(x)$ is $0$ on $(-\infty, 0)$. If $f$ is at some point non-zero, we could (by the Mean Value Theorem) find a $c$ so that $f'(c)$ is non-zero. This would give us an infinite number of $f^{(n)}(c_n)$'s that are non-zero. My thought is that this would eventually force $f^{(n)}$ to be non-differentiable, a contradiction. My intuition here is $f$ is going to look like a piecewise function, which generally aren't differentiable at the "boundary" between the pieces. An example I have in mind is that
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}0 & x \leq 0;\\ x^2 & x > 0 \end{cases}$$
is differentiable, but not twice differentiable at $0$; both sides ''agree'' that the first derivative should be $0$, but the difference quotient doesn't match when taking a left- vs. right-sided limit for the second derivative.

Is this even a true statement? Are there counterexamples to it? If not, what would be the right way to prove it?

Comment: No. The set of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Consider $f(x)=0$ if $x \le 0$, $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ otherwise.

Comment: Check out this Wikipedia article on bump functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function

Comment: I will note however that your intuition isn't too far off. If you wanted your function to be entire in the complex plane, than this sort of thing could not happen. Every time you have this "bump" function there is hidden singular behaviour. If you consider the $f$ I defined, extended to complex plane, there is an essential singularity at $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A well known example of an infinitely differentiable function vanishing on negative real line is $f(x)=e^{-1/x}$ for $x>0$ and $0$ for $x \leq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Such functions exist and are very useful. For example $\exp(-1/x^2)$ for $x>0$ and $0$ for $x\le 0$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Are you asking me?

Comment: No, I am just curious about downvotes.

Comment: @copper.hat  It may be because this answer came a few minutes after the accepted answer. Not a good reason to downvote, but I've seen worse ...

Comment: @zhw:  I do not think it is the reason. There are several users here who downvote all my questions and most answers.

Comment: @JCAA Yes it is possible to attract stalkers. In that case you can alert MSE staff.